# XSSFCellStyle setFillForegroundColor and setFillBackgroundColor doesn't work

Tags: java, xssf

I tried to use setFillForegroundColor and setFillBackgroundColor to change the cell color of an excel file.

However, I failed and I really didn't know what the problem was. I've googled for many hours and still couldn't find the right way to set the color.

The following is the code I write:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestColor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("no blue");

        // set the color of the cell
        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(Color.BLUE);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(myColor);
        cell.setCellStyle(style); // this command seems to fail

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            wb.write(fos);
            wb.close();
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the final result.

[image]

How can I set the cell's color to blue?

I'm using poi-bin-3.12-20150511.zip from https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Does it set the value of cell A1 to "123" ?

Comment: Sorry, my code should be "no blue" instead of "123".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may need to add the following line after setting the foreground colour:

```
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Comment: Since POI 3.x the right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46996790/3790512

Answer (score 18):

[SetFillPattern](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillPattern-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType-) expects FillPatterType, so rather this:

```
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
```