# Set BackgroundColor in XSSFWorkbook with Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to set my own backgroundcolor in XSSFWorkbook.
So far i have this code:

```
 style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setFont(itemFont);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128)));  
    styles.put("item_right", style);
```

But i got the following error:

> The method setFillForegroundColor(short) in the type CellStyle is not >applicable for the arguments (XSSFColor)
>
> The constructor XSSFColor(Color) is deprecated

So how can i set my own color in XSSFWorkbook ?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion here ? [Java Apache Poi, how to set background color and borders at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874115/java-apache-poi-how-to-set-background-color-and-borders-at-same-time/46996790) or, in other words, ` backgroundStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());`

Comment: `cs.setFillForegroundColor(
    new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()).getIndex());` <-- not tested though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution :

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), null));
```

It's not deprecated with last version.