# The method setFillForegroundColor(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFColor)

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am trying to get custom colours to work in Apache POI but I got into a small problem. So far I have been using `IndexedColors`, but as a palette, it is pretty drab. Thus using an RGB format for colour selection would help me to make my spreadsheets look much better.

I have been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685471/set-backgroundcolor-in-xssfworkbook-with-java) question's answer, as it solves my problem theoretically. However, I am facing a very silly problem that I do not really know how to solve.

The error I receive is:

> The method setFillForegroundColor(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFColor)

This should not really be happening, as I have seen it being used in many other examples and documentation about Apache POI. The IDE (Eclipse) suggests changing `setFillForegroundColor` to `setFillBackgroundColor` but doing this, only makes the idea suggest the vice versa as a solution. What a joker can my IDE be...

I have created a `Map` for my styles and that could be somehow convoluting everything but I do not really believe that this is the issue. Or could it?

What can I do to solve this nonsense?

---

Code excerpt:

```
private static Map<String, CellStyle> styling(Workbook wb)
{
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<>();
    CellStyle style;

    Font font1 = wb.createFont();
    font1.setBold(true);

    style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    style.setFont(font1);
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND); 
    styles.put("column_headers", style);

    return styles;
}
```

Some visual comedy

[setFillBackgroundColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKwvP.png)

[setFillForegroundColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeljE.png)

Comment: The method [public void setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) is an additional method of [XSSFCellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html). It is not a method of `Interface` [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) I solved the issue. The problem is that I should have sticked to the XSSF libraries.

```
private static Map<String, CellStyle> styling(Workbook wb)
{
  Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<>();
  XSSFCellStyle style;

  Font font1 = wb.createFont();
  font1.setBold(true);
  style = (XSSFCellStyle) createBorderedStyle(wb);
  style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
  style.setFont(font1);
  style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
  style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND); 
  styles.put("cell_g", style);

  return styles; 
}
```